# Laravel Echo Vue Js TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, pusher

I'm having an issue particularly with Vue Js hoping someone can point me in the right direction. I am using Laravel's Echo feature which is connected to Pusher. I currently am getting data back from pusher that part is fine and dandy. The issue I can't seem to figure out is on the client side code. I'm trying to add the new items coming from pusher to the already existing items on my page. However when I use this.items.push() within the Echo channel block I am receiving a console error with TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined. I am thinking that "this.items" is out of scope?

```
<div id="app">
    <ul id="example-1">
        <li v-for="item in items">
            @{{ item }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
    new Vue({

        el: '#app',

        data: {
            items: []
        },
        mounted: function () {
            this.listen();
        },

        methods: {
            /**
             * Listen to the Echo channels
             */
            listen: function() {

                // pushed fine from here
                this.items.push("dddd");

                Echo.channel('test_channel')
                    .listen('OrderCreated', function(e) {
                        //TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
                        this.items.push('elkqwejfh')
                    });
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scope of `this` changes inside `Echo.channel`, you have save `this` in a different variable and use that variable inside instead of `this`, That's why it work perfectly outside `Echo.channel` but inside `this.items` is null, so it throws error. You need to make following changes:

```
    methods: {
        /**
         * Listen to the Echo channels
         */
        listen: function() {

            // pushed fine from here
            this.items.push("dddd");
            var self = this
            Echo.channel('test_channel')
                .listen('OrderCreated', function(e) {
                    //TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
                   self.items.push('elkqwejfh')
                });
        }
```